# How to get parent XML node by using PySpark

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In the application I'm developing, I need to analyze with Spark various XML files, whose structure changes from file to file. In other words, I have some XML feeds with similar data but different data structures. For each of these feed, I'm writing the relevant importing software (I'm using Python, hence PySpark, since I prefer it over Java and Scala).

I've analyzed almost every feed, except two of these, which share a common "defect". In all the other feeds, I have two XML files, one named "agenzie.xml" (or something like that), which is substantially a table which contains all the data about all the vendors registered on the website that supplies me the feed, one named "annunci.xml", which contains all the data about the ads that the vendors give me. In these two files - I'll [link](https://pastebin.com/vjY2JXBL) just one but the other one is very similar - I have a hierarchical structure, something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <vendor>
        <info1></info1>
        <info2></info2>
        <ads>
            <ad>
                <info1_about_ad></info1_about_ad>
                <info2_about_ad></info2_about_ad>
            </ad>
        </ads>
    </vendor>
    <vendor>
        <info1></info1>
        <info2></info2>
        <ads>
            <ad>
                <info1_about_ad></info1_about_ad>
                <info2_about_ad></info2_about_ad>
            </ad>
        </ads>
    </vendor>
</root>
```

The code I use to create the dataframe is:

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(rowTag="ad").load("gs://bucket-HIDDEN/import/it/HIDDEN/HIDDEN.xml").repartition(3)
my_rdd = df.rdd.map(Convert) # Convert is a method I've written
```

My problem is that I don't know how to have access, from Convert, to the `info1` or `info2` fields of the parent XML nodes. I was thinking about to use `vendor` as `rowTag`, and change `ads` in an array, but I think that it would cause a bottleneck since the data I have to analyze weight about 5 GB, and while other feeds would be analyzed fastly (without this workaround), these two feeds would be analyzed too slowly.

Comment: If PySpark is not your only choice you can try this: 

`from xml.etree import ElementTree`
`root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)`

Comment: I've written every parser with PySpark, I can't move away from it, sorry